# How to plot probability density with rose plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram, normalization, rose-plot

I am trying to plot normalized, probability histogram with rose function in matlab (I can't use polarhistogram because I do not have the latest version of Matlab. My version is 2015b).

In a normal histogram, I usually do it like this:

```
h = histogram(x,'Normalization','probability');
```

But the same doesn't work for rose. 
If I try passing h.Values to rose plot, this doesn't work, because the rose uses this as the data, not as values...

```
x=rand(100)*90;
xRad = x(:)./180*pi;
xRadProb = histogram(xRad,'Normalization','probability');
figure(1)
hax = axes();
rose(hax, xRadProb.Values,10)
```

Any suggestions how to do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to do the normalization yourself. But it's easy. 
For `'probability'`,  the normalization simply consists in dividing the un-normalized result (count for each bin) by the total number of data values.

So, use the two-ouput version or `rose`, normalize, and then use [`polar`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) (in R2015b) or [`polarplot`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html) (in more recent Matlab versions) to do the polar plot:

```
[t, r] = rose(xRad, 100); % 100 is desired number of bins. Set as needed
r = r./numel(xRad); % normalize
polar(t, r) % polar plot
```

[image]

As a check, following is the result of `polarhistogram` with the same number of bins. Note that in this function the bins are adjusted to the actual data range, so `25` needs to be specified instead of `100` in the example:

```
polarhistogram(xRad, 25, 'Normalization', 'probability')
```

[image]